# Calling Table-Valued SQL Functions From .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Scalar-valued functions can be called from .NET as follows:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("testFunction", sqlConn); //testFunction is scalar
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
cmd.Parameters.Add("retVal", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["retVal"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int aFunctionResult = (int)cmd.Parameters["retVal"].Value;
```

I also know that table-valued functions can be called in a similar fashion, for example:

```
String query = "select * from testFunction(param1,...)"; //testFunction is table-valued
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(tbl);
```

My question is, can table-valued functions be called as stored procedures, like scalar-valued functions can? (e.g., replicate my first code snippet with a table-valued function being called and getting the returned table through a ReturnValue parameter).

Comment: @ChuckConway Why dropping C# from the title?  It was valid, considering the C# tag... but that tag does not help it, to show up in google.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No because you need to select them.  However you can create a stored proc wrapper, which may defeat the point of having a table function.

Comment: I don't think it would really defeat the point of having a table-valued function.  One point of having TVFs is that they have certain safety guarantees that stored procedures do not.  Another point is that they can be re-used, whereas it is much more difficult to reuse a stored procedure without simply copy and pasting.